# Logging messages from __init__.py of an imported module in Python

Tags: python, logging, import, python-import, python-logging

I wrote some libraries and part of the code relies on environment variables.

Therefor the **init**.py files of those libraries have some logic to parse env files or set defaults.

Since this envvars influence the code, I set up a logger in **init**.py and I am logging whether an env file was found etc.

If I am now writing a skript and want to configure a logger, I am missing those messages if I don't configure the logger before the import. On the other hand imports should come first.

What is a better way to solve this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple options:

1. Break the "imports come first" rule -- it's not unheard of b/c there are sometimes good reasons to do this, but I'd consider it a bit of a hack in your case, i.e. what you should probably do is:
2. Don't read the env files/vars at the top level, which executes on module import.

It sounds like you're doing something like:

```py
# foo.py
import os

CONFIG = os.getenv('SOMETHING')  # this runs module is imported, i.e. the file is loaded
```

```py
# main.py
import foo  # right here

# do stuff, but toplevel code in foo.py has already executed
```

Instead:

```py
# foo.py
import os
import functools as ft

@ft.cache
def config():
    return os.getenv('SOMETHING')  # inside a function, not top-level
```

```py
# main.py
import foo

# at this point, foo.config() has been defined, but not executed

configure_logger()

foo.config()
foo.config()  # return value is cached, so same value is returned without re-executing

# do stuff
```

Comment: The details differ a bit, but it's in principle what I am doing. I don't have this env resolving in an extra function for ease of use. I want my users to be able to just import the module and start using it. If one has always to run foo.config() it's a bit confusing isn't it?

Comment: Additionally, I have conditional imports in one library. If I want to log, whether the import took place, I have no chance then option 1, right?

Comment: Confusing? Not at all. I dislike it when libraries execute global code on import, because b/c it can cause import order issues, esp when multiple libs are doing it. Why don't you give users both options? `import foo.boot` for "boot on import", which just calls methods in `import foo`, which users can call themselves for "manual boot". Option 2 can still do everything you want, e.g. conditional imports, so still not seeing a reason to prefer option 1.

Comment: I don't understand how that would work. When I import the package or modules of the package all imports in them are done too. Only way zo circumvent it would be to have imports in the config function. But then I just migrated the tooic into the package and have imports not at the top.

Comment: comments aren't a good place to describe in detail. If you ask a new question specifically about that, I can take a look -- just link it here.

Comment: Here is a more elaborated question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76233267/python-logging-of-conditional-imports-in-libraries