# Python logging of conditional imports in libraries

Tags: python, logging, import, python-logging

I have a library with a module that does an conditional import.

I want to be able in my applications to log the outcome of the conditional import. But that forces me to configure my handlers etc. before the import of that module, which is regarded bad style.

The module looks something like that.

```
from logging import getLogger
import foo

try:
    import bar as br
    BAR_INSTALLED = True
    msg = "bar is imported."
except ImportError:
    BAR_INSTALLED = False
    msg = "bar is not available."


logger = getLogger(__main__)
logger.info(msg)
```

Bonus question: Pycharm is complaining that br is not defined in the except clause. I really don't need it, because in that case you really have to force yoursslf to import the wrong function and try to use it wizhout br. Should one care about it?

Edit: Regarding the comments on the bonus question, I changed the code to the following:

my_package/my_module.py

```
from logging import getLogger
import foo

try:
    import bar as br
except ImportError:
    br = None


logger = getLogger(__main__)

if br:
    msg = "bar is imported."
else:
    msg = "bar is not available."

logger.info(msg)
```

To make it more clear. I have a completly other script in an environment where I installed my_package.
In this script I want to log whether br was installed that currently forces me to to something like:

```
import logging.config


logging.config.dictConfig(config_dict)

import my_package


# other code
```

Comment: You still need to define `br` in the `except` block, just do something like `br = None`. Otherwise PyCharm will complain about execution branches not having the name being defined with something.

Comment: Also, you don't need `BAR_INSTALLED` nor `msg`, do as @metatoaster suggests, and check for `bool(br)`. But overall, having a conditional import like this is common. You'll find it in plenty of popular Python libs.

Comment: Thanks Kache and metatoaster that is both helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I've created an example which defines the `logger` in a separate file. Subsequently, you import the instantiated `logger` instead of the `logging` module.

For more information about logging, Python's official documentation offers a neat cookbook which shows you some handy features of the `logging` module ([link](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html))

I've saved `logger.py` in a directory called `src`. The folder structure is as follows:

```
├── src
│   ├── logger.py
├── main.py
```

This is the code in `logger.py`

```
# logger.py
import logging
import logging.config

logger = logging.getLogger('simpleExample')
```

And this is the code in `main.py`

```
# main.py
from src.logger import logger

try:
    import tensorflow
    
except ImportError:
    logger.warning('tensorflow could not be loaded!')

if __name__=='__main__':

    logger.info('executing __main__')
```

Let me know if this helped!

Comment: Hmm, maybe I should it more clear. It's more that I have the conditional import alreadyin the library. But if I want to capture that message in my script, I need to configure the loggers before importing main in your example.